# Python open or create file using with clause

Tags: python

I have the following code, but it doesn't work if the file doesn't exist:

```
def log(self, action, data):
    import json
    with open('ReservationsManagerApp/logs/'+data['booking']+'.json', 'r+') as outfile:
        log_data = {
            'timestamp': str(datetime.today()),
            'action': action,
            'data': data
        }
        json.dump(log_data, outfile)
```

I want the method to create the file if it doesn't exist, but all the examples I have found don't explain how to do it using `with` clause, they just use `try: open`.
How can I instruct `with` clause to create the file if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Have you tried w+ instead of r+?

Comment: You can just next the `with` inside the `try`, these are two separate, composable constructs. However, there may be a mode that allows you to not have to use `try-except`

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher `w+` will truncate if it exists. Likely, the OP wants `'a'` mode, i.e. "append"

Comment: Oh yes, that's true. Anyway all these modes are easily retrieved from the open documentation, i.e. the question is moot, open does create the file if required.

Comment: For reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher yep. I usually have to look them up, I've just learned the hard way that w+ truncates :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the file in `a+` mode (append mode with the permission to read) instead, and do a file seek to position 0 so that it creates the file if it doesn't already exist, but also allows reading the file from the beginning:

```
with open('ReservationsManagerApp/logs/'+data['booking']+'.json', 'a+') as outfile:
    outfile.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The mode `r+` is read+write, but does not create the file if needed.  I think you want `w+`.  Nice [table here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r).

Comment: Already said in the comment.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: Putting answers in comments defeats the purpose of StackOverflow.  However, happy to remove my answer if you move your answer to the answer section.

Comment: Well, isn't your link basically saying this is a duplicate? So no need for any answer here.

Comment: No. While related, that question does not ask anything about the "open or create" functionality this user is looking for.  One of the answers does contain a useful table, however.

Comment: That's your opinion. For me, and for lots of people, this is a duplicate, as OP wants to create a file. The fact that it's in a `with` clause doesn't change the original problem.

Comment: Without question I'm expressing only my opinion, sorry if I wasn't clear.  At present, based on the number of close-as-duplicate votes, it appears one person only believes it's a duplicate.

Comment: Obviously, Python tag has a far lower barrier than stricter tags where this would already be closed. All depends on the number of questions I guess.

Comment: In your opinion, of course. . .